# Store style.color inside variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store style.color of input element inside javascript variable but it always shows me empty string.

```
var textColor = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color = textColor;
console.log(textColor);
```

Comment: You're storing the entire input element in the `textColor` variable?!

Comment: But I can't do it like that var textColor = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color

Comment: Why not? Also, can you show us the HTML of your page? What value do you expect to get?

Answer (score -1):

You need to access the input's .value property, a hex color.

Answer (score -1):

...I think you mean

```js
var textColor = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
textColor.style.color = textColor.value;
console.log(textColor.value);
```

Comment: This will console.log the value of input and I need to have access to style.color like "blue" etc...

Comment: Then change textColor.value to textColor.style.color

Comment: I already tried it and it shows [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: The reason it says that, is because you're logging the entire object of the element. You can get the color with style.color;

Comment: Yes, so I do it like that textColor = textColor.style.color; and it shows an empty log

Comment: The element must have an empty color then.

Comment: No it has black color

Comment: @GPB But not in a `style="color: black"` attribute for sure? If you want to get styles applied by style sheets, you need to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: No I was not right, because I am fetching the data from input element of google site and it has no color value in it

Comment: Is it possible to store the data about text color from google.com?

Comment: Yes, but it's quite impossible and useless without a server. You can scrape the source code from google.com (http request), get the html code, and read the code and use `getComputedStyle` to get the color. You should just look at google company colors.

Comment: I am asking because my app is not only fetching the data from google input but also from website with dark background and now it sounds like really tough problem to store original text color.